# Product Id Retrieval with database

Tags: scala, slick

I fist encountered this problem when I was using other ORMs. I couldn't find a better solution. Now I use Slick and PlayFramework, so I think maybe there is one.

Suppose I have two tables in my database: `Tags` and `Product`.

I'm getting information from a single HTML form containing both product data and tag data. Tags are associated with the product, so naturally I have another table called `Product_Tag` for this bidirectional relationship.

Then I store the info for Product. My Product slick code looks like this:

```
Object Product extends Table[Product]("Products") {
    def id = column[Int]("PRD_ID", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
    def name = column[String]("PRD_NAME")
    ...
}
```

Tag code looks similar. Here is the code for Product_Tag:

```
Object Product_Tag extends Table[Product_Tag]("Product_Tags") {
  def prd_id = column[Int]("PRD_ID")
  def tag_id = column[Int]("TAG_ID")
  def tag_name = column[String]("TAG_NAME")
  ....
}
```

I should store the tags associated with that product when product is saved. I use this code to save it:

```
Product.insert(None, "product A")
```

Now the problem becomes, how can I store the association between the tag and the product when I don't even know their IDs? Yes, I could save the `tag` and `product` first and then retrieve them to have the ID but I hate doing that because I feel inefficient.

Is there anyway to work around this? Java's UUID??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up an autoInc projection to get it to return the id with the insert, like:

```
// In the same place as your * projection
def autoInc = id.? ~ name <> (Product.apply _, Product.unapply _) returning id

// In your client code
val id = Product.autoInc.insert(Product(...))
```

More info about that here: https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/10

Slightly unrelated: It looks like you tried to insert a product with a `None` id and you are on Slick 1.0.  Some databases (like `postgres`) will flip a table when you try to insert a null into your primary key column for autoInc like you are doing above.  In that case you'd either have to remove the id from your insert projection, or just upgrade to slick 2.0 which handles this more gracefully.

If you're just starting on a new project I highly recommend just moving to 2.0 now.

Comment: Hey I have updated to Slick 2.0 and is undergoing a lot of changes..I applied the `returning id` but my IDE says `type mismatch: Query[NotInferedRT, NotInferedRU], actual: Column[Int]`.

Comment: Yeah there are a bunch of changes in how slick 2.0 works vs slick 1.0, but they've upgraded the documentation on the site as well.  For specific changes between the versions, this should be helpful: http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.0/migration.html  For a specific example of what you want to do, https://github.com/slick/slick-examples/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/slick/examples/lifted/MultiDBCakeExample.scala (around line 26-27)